# Override/Extend Magento Abstract class?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, overriding, extend

I only need to add a method to the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract class.

For that, in my config.php I have

```
<models>
     <mymodule>
         <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
     </mymodule>
     <core>
         <rewrite>
             <mage_core_model_abstract>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Abstract</mage_core_model_abstract>
         </rewrite>
     </core>
</models>
```

It doesn't really work..

I know that there is a way of "overriding" by copying all the folder structure including the  class file into my module, but I would like to know if there is a way to make it more fancy, within my module - something similar as above..

Comment: Often (not always), when there is a need to override a superclass, there is a better way. What ar you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Which is the better way? Please share! In this particular case, let's say I need to create a new method in order to provide it to all children and on the other hand to add some additional logic to an existing one..

Comment: The potential for a "better" way depends on your need and whether it can be accommodated by the event architecture; what you want to do *specifically* in a "new" method would determine this. If there is a need to uniformly change a method defined in an abstract, the best way *is* the path-based override rather than repeat the logic again and again for subclasses (IMO, DRY > owning a core definition).

Comment: Thanks! I have thought about using events in order to solve my problem, but there is non that fits..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only rewrite classes that you instantiate directly, from `config.xml`.

The various values in `config.xml` are used when creating an object through a factory (e.g. `Mage::getModel($class)`, `Mage::getSingleton($class)`, `Mage::helper($class)`, etc).  The value of the `$class` argument is used to translate `catalog/product` into `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.

This means it's impossible to *rewrite* (in the Magento sense) classes that are used as superclasses, including abstract classes (by definition).

If you want to *redefine* any class that's used as a superclass, then you'll need to place a file in the correct place further up the include path.  In this case, you'd need to make a file in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php`.

Comment: Yes, even if I don't really like it, seems to be the only solution.. Thanks!

Comment: Why does just making a copy not work for me? I have the same path, `core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php` -> `local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php`, but it is not loading the local, just the core. Is there another step that is not mentioned?