# Do want remove wishlist items when add all to cart

Tags: magento, cart

I open `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php`
And change  `$item->addToCart($cart, true);` to  `$item->addToCart($cart, false);`
to keep items in wishlist when I add it to cart.
But it just effect when I add each items.
When I click "Add all to cart" button. All product items are removed.
I want to keep it in wishlist after add all to cart.
Have anybody know how to do it? Please help me!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This one is handled in the Mage_Wishlist_Controller_Abstract on line 108:

```
// Add to cart
if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
    $addedItems[] = $item->getProduct();
}
```

as it is your personal Wishlist `$isOwner` is `true` and deletes the items.

And as there is no way to override abstract classes, you have to copy the Abstract and IndexController in your own Module and do your modifications there.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742381/900326